# Assembly: Issues with Indexing

Tags: arrays, assembly, indexing, x86, masm

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the indexing in my loops. I know `esi` is used for indexing, so I'm attempting to use that...

```
    scores DWORD MAXIMUMSCORES DUP(0)
optionPromptMsg byte "Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: ", 0
scorePromptMsg      byte "Enter your numeric score (0-100): ", 0
scoreErrorMsg       byte "Score out of range (0-100)!", 0
optionErrorMsg      byte "Only 0 or 1 allowed in option specification!", 0
resultMsg           byte " scores have been entered.", 0


.code
main proc
mov esi, 0
L1:
    mov edx, offset optionPromptMsg
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov ebx, 1
    cmp eax, ebx
    je L2
    mov ebx, -1               //99% sure my main is okay
    cmp eax, ebx
    je L3
    mov ebx, -2
    mov ecx, 2
    cmp ebx, eax
    ja L4
    cmp eax, ecx
    ja L4
    L2: call NextScore
    jmp L5
    L4: mov edx, offset optionErrorMsg
        call WriteString
        call Crlf
        jmp L5
    L5:
    loop L1
        L3 : call WriteScore



exit
main ENDP



WriteScore PROC USES esi //Thought was somehow make esi global?

mov eax, lengthof scores  //total number of items added to array
call writeInt
mov edx, offset resultMsg   
call WriteString
mov esi,0
L1:
    mov eax, scores[esi *4]
    call writeInt    //writes the numbers in the array
    inc esi
loop L1
mov eax, 5000
call Delay


ret
WriteScore ENDP

NextScore PROC USES esi

mov edx, offset scorePromptMsg
call WriteString
call ReadInt
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, 100       
cmp ebx, eax
ja L1
cmp eax,ecx
ja L1
jmp L2
L1:
    mov edx, offset scoreErrorMsg
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
L2:
    mov scores[esi*4], eax //gets the next number and puts it in the array
    inc esi

ret
NextScore ENDP
```

When I run it, and add 3 items to the array, it for whatever reason says the lengthof `scores` is 20, and then when it prints out the array, the numbers aren't even close to what I'm expecting, normally in the millions or just `0`.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Add the remainder of the source. At a _bare minimum_, the code needs to include your `ReadInt` and `WriteString` functions. Also, you should be running this in a debugger - If this is dos-based, use Turbo Debugger You'll see your mistake in no time if you debug your code. ;)

Comment: @enhnzflep I'm using visual studio to write it and the debugger for it is well.. dog sh*t in my opinion. Whats this turbo debugger you speak of? And what do you mean by adding the remainder of the source?

Comment: @enhzflep : He's using the Irvine32 library. Some useful info on it is [here](http://math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/cs221/handouts/procedures.pdf)

Comment: Half your luck! Funnily enough, the only reason I have VS installed is for its debugger.. Turbo Debugger wont help you, since it's meant for 16 bit programs that run under dos (or DosBox).  @MichaelPetch - oh, I see. :sniff:

Comment: His code is 32-bit so if he has the library set up he should be able to easily use the debugger in VS.

Comment: This can't be all your code. Among other things I don't see `MAXIMUMSCORES` defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues. One is that you don't seem to understand what the `USES` directive on a procedure/function is for. If you use `USES` and list a register(s) then that tells the assembler to save the value of those registers on the stack, and restore them just before the function exits. This means that any change you make to that register in that function will not be seen by the function that called it.

The MASM manual says this about **USES**:

> Syntax:   USES reglist
>
> Description:
>
> ```
>  An optional keyword used with PROC. Generates code to push the
>  value of registers that should be preserved (and that will be
>  altered by your procedure) on the stack and pop them off when the
>  procedure returns.
>
>  The <reglist> parameter is a list of one or more registers. Separate
>  multiple registers with spaces.
> ```

Since you seem to want changes to *ESI* made in the function *NextScore* to be seen by the calling function you will want to remove the *USES* statement from that procedure. Change:

```
NextScore PROC USES esi
```

to:

```
NextScore PROC
```

Now when you increment *ESI* in next score it won't be undone when the function exits.

Another issue is that the [lengthof](http://www.oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_8/CH08-5.html) pseudo-opcode does:

> lengthof: Returns the number of items in array variable.

It may not be clear but this pseudo-opcode is the number of elements in the array when the code was assembled. You define the array of scores like this:

```
scores DWORD MAXIMUMSCORES DUP(0)
```

The *scores* array will always have a lengthof value of *MAXIMUMSCORES*. Rather than use *lengthof* what you should be doing is simply using the *ESI* register. You already use *ESI* to keep a count of elements you have added to the array. So this code:

```
WriteScore PROC USES esi ; Thought was somehow make esi global?

    mov eax, lengthof scores  ; total number of items added to array
    call WriteInt
```

Can be changed to:

```
WriteScore PROC USES esi ; Thought was somehow make esi global?

    mov eax, esi  ; esi = number of items added to array
    call WriteInt
```

Another issue is that it appears you don't know how the `loop` instruction works. From the [x86 Instruction Set] the `loop` instruction does:

> Performs a loop operation using the ECX or CX register as a counter.
>   Each time the LOOP instruction is executed, the count register is
>   decremented, then checked for 0. If the count is 0, the loop is
>   terminated and program execution continues with the instruction
>   following the LOOP instruction. If the count is not zero, a near jump
>   is performed to the destination (target) operand, which is presumably
>   the instruction at the beginning of the loop.

In your code you never set *ECX* to the number of times you wish to loop, so it will use whatever value happens to be in *ECX* . This is why you have a lot of extra numbers printed out. *ECX* needs to be initialized. Since you want to loop through all the scores entered, you simply move *ESI* to *ECX*. Your WriteScore function did:

```
    mov esi,0
L1:
    mov eax, scores[esi *4]
    call WriteInt    ; writes the numbers in the array
    inc esi
    loop L1
```

We can modify it to be:

```
    mov ecx,esi      ; Initialize ECX loop counter to number of scores added
                     ; to the array.
    mov esi,0
L1:
    mov eax, scores[esi *4]
    call WriteInt    ; writes the numbers in the array
    inc esi
    loop L1
```

Now we just loop through the number of scores (*ESI*) the user actually entered.

With these changes in mind your program could look something like this:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDELIB Irvine32.lib
INCLUDELIB user32.lib
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib

MAXIMUMSCORES equ 20

.data
scores DWORD MAXIMUMSCORES DUP(0)
optionPromptMsg byte "Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: ", 0
scorePromptMsg      byte "Enter your numeric score (0-100): ", 0
scoreErrorMsg       byte "Score out of range (0-100)!", 0
optionErrorMsg      byte "Only 0 or 1 allowed in option specification!", 0
resultMsg           byte " scores have been entered.", 0

.code
main proc
    mov esi, 0
L1:
    mov edx, offset optionPromptMsg
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov ebx, 1
    cmp eax, ebx
    je L2
    mov ebx, -1               ; 99% sure my main is okay
    cmp eax, ebx
    je L3
    mov ebx, -2
    mov ecx, 2
    cmp ebx, eax
    ja L4
    cmp eax, ecx
    ja L4
L2: call NextScore
    jmp L5
L4: mov edx, offset optionErrorMsg
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    jmp L5
L5:
    loop L1
L3: call WriteScore

    exit
main ENDP

WriteScore PROC USES esi ; We make changes to ESI not visible to caller
                         ; since we don't intend to change the number of scores
                         ; with this function. Any change to ESI in this function
                         ; will not appear to the caller of this function

    mov eax, esi      ; total number of items added to array in ESI
    call WriteInt
    mov edx, offset resultMsg
    call WriteString
    mov ecx,esi
    mov esi,0
L1:
    mov eax, scores[esi *4]
    call WriteInt    ; writes the numbers in the array
    inc esi
    loop L1
    mov eax, 5000
    call Delay
    ret
WriteScore ENDP

NextScore PROC ; We want changes to ESI to exist after we exit this function. ESI
               ; will effectively act as a global register.
    mov edx, offset scorePromptMsg
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, 100
    cmp ebx, eax
    ja L1
    cmp eax,ecx
    ja L1
    jmp L2
L1:
    mov edx, offset scoreErrorMsg
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
L2:
    mov scores[esi*4], eax ; gets the next number and puts it in the array
    inc esi

    ret
NextScore ENDP

END
```

Sample output of this:

```
Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: 1
Enter your numeric score (0-100): 10
Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: 1
Enter your numeric score (0-100): 20
Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: 1
Enter your numeric score (0-100): 40
Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: 1
Enter your numeric score (0-100): 650
Score out of range (0-100)!
Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: 99
Only 0 or 1 allowed in option specification!
Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: 1
Enter your numeric score (0-100): 100
Type 1 to continue or -1 to exit: -1
+5 scores have been entered.+10+20+40+650+100
```

Comment: OHHH okay! Not sure why, but I was under the impression esi was the counter for the loop! Keep forgetting that's `ecx`'s job. Brilliant explanation @Michael_Petch, truly showed why and how everything works.

Comment: @user38254 You might have been thinking of the [movsb, movsw, movsl](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-movsb.html) type instructions.